# Multiple outlets with ember.js - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I just looked into ember.js (rc7) and tried to build an example with multiple outlets.

index.html

```
<html>
    // ... head and other meta definitions
    <body>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
            <p>Hello Index!</p>
        </script>

        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="products">
            {{outlet header}}

            <p>Hello Products 22!</p>

            {{outlet footer}}
        </script>

        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="header">
            <p>Header</p>
        </script>

        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="footer">
            <p>Footer</p>
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ember.js/ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/application.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

application.js

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('products');
});

App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function () {
        this.render('header', {
            outlet: 'header',
            into: 'products'
        });

        this.render('footer', {
            outlet: 'footer',
            into: 'products'
        });
    }
});
```

Unfortunately when running this code, the javascript console prints out an error from ember.js: Error while loading route: TypeError {}.

Stacktrace from Google console:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:364
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.7 ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:364
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0 ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:364
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.10.0 ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:364
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:364
Error while loading route: TypeError {} ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:364
(anonymous function) ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:364
Ember.Router.reopenClass._defaultErrorHandler ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:26567
trigger ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:25709
handlerEnteredOrUpdated ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:25591
handler ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:25566
eachHandler ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:25613
setupContexts ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:25565
finalizeTransition ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:25886
transitionSuccess ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:25781
invokeCallback ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:7271
Promise.then ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:7321
EventTarget.trigger ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:7094
config.async.promise.trigger.detail ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:7384
DeferredActionQueues.flush ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:4744
Backburner.end ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:4830
Backburner.run ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:4869
Ember.run ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:5200
Ember.Application.Ember.Namespace.extend.scheduleInitialize ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js:29937
x.Callbacks.c jquery.js:3064
x.Callbacks.p.fireWith jquery.js:3176
x.extend.ready jquery.js:433
q jquery.js:104
```

I am pretty sure I messed something up, so any hint would be appreciated. Thanks!

Thierry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you will have to add a call to `super` in `renderTemplate`, otherwise the products template won't be rendered and you want to render into it :-)

```
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function (controller, context) {
        this._super(controller, context);
        this.render('header', {
            outlet: 'header',
            into: 'products'
        });

        this.render('footer', {
            outlet: 'footer',
            into: 'products'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the correct. And is possible to use this._super(controller, context), this.render(), or this.render('products');

Answer (score 1):

I think **mavilein** provided the solution.

The problem here is that we have not rendered the parent template at the outset.

We can also do the following.

```
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
renderTemplate: function () {
    this.render('products');
    this.render('header', {
        outlet: 'header',
        into: 'products'
    });

    this.render('footer', {
        outlet: 'footer',
        into: 'products'
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that jumps out to me is that you're missing the application template, which is kind of the master layout for the application. Not sure if it will fix the error, but it could just be something like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Comment: If the application template is not there, the template you posted is exactly the one, which is generated.

Answer (score 0):

To all the answers there is one thing to add tough, in your router map you have to define that the `products` route is located at `/` since it seams that you don't care about the index template at all:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('products', {path: '/'});
});
```

See for a demo [here](http://jsbin.com/odosoy/66/edit).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, the example above is just for demo purposes, but thanks anyway for pointing out.